# How to increment column value during on_conflict_do_update?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy, upsert

I would like to insert a row if it does not break unique values across product_id and date columns (not added as a unique constraint), and if it does I just want to increment the column value in the existing row.

I think i have to use: 
`on_conflict_do_update()`
But I cannot find out what should I type for the index/constraint and set_arguments.

Can you guys point me the direction? :)

Model:

```
class MyModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'my_model'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date)
    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('product.id'))
    counter = Column(Integer)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me, using Postgresql:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import insert

class my_table(Base):                                                                                                                        
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 
    counter = Column(Integer)                                                                                                                

insert_stmt = insert(my_table).\
    values(id=42).\
    on_conflict_do_update(index_elements=[my_table.id],
                          set_=dict(counter=my_table.counter+1)).\
    returning(my_table.id)

results = session.execute(insert_stmt)
```

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html?highlight=conflict#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.dml.Insert.on_conflict_do_nothing

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc here [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/changelog/migration_12.html#support-for-insert-on-duplicate-key-update), you can give it a try:

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import insert

insert_stmt = insert(my_table). \
    values(id='some_id', data='some data to insert')

on_conflict_stmt = insert_stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(
    data=insert_stmt.inserted.data,
    status='U'
)

conn.execute(on_conflict_stmt)
```